# How can I pass email displaying in DialogContentText to axios put request

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks

How can I  pass `ratePlyrEmail` to calculateAvgRating() during on click on submit button.
The player email will displays randomly in the `<Input  type="hidden" name="playertorate" value={email} onChange={onChange}></Input>` of DialogContentText every time when the user click on Enter Player Rating button. I have added `onChange` in the DialogContentText. Now I am getting only `rating` and `loginUserEmail` in server side.

```
const [ratePlyrEmail, setRatePlyrEmail] = useState({ playertorate: ''});
 const [rating, setRating] = useState({
      shooting: "",
      dribbling: "",
      ballcontrol: "",
      sprinting: "",
      fitness: ""
    });
 const [ratingTotal, setRatingTotal] = useState(0);

 const onChange = e => {
    e.persist();
    const ratingValues = {
      ...rating,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    };
    setRating(ratingValues);
    
    const rateEmailValue = {
      ...ratePlyrEmail,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    }
    setRatePlyrEmail(rateEmailValue);
    ratingCalculation(ratingValues);

  };

  const ratingCalculation = ratingValues =>{
    const {
      shooting,
      dribbling,
      ballcontrol,
      sprinting,
      fitness
    } = ratingValues;
    const newTotal =
      Number(shooting) +
      Number(dribbling) +
      Number(ballcontrol) +
      Number(sprinting) +
      Number(fitness);
    const finalAvg = newTotal / 5;
    setRatingTotal(finalAvg);
    return ratingTotal ;
  }


   const calculateAvgRating = (rating) => {
    const sendPlayerRating = async () => {
      try {
      const params = {
      email: loginUserEmail,
      };
      const res = await axios.put('http://localhost:8000/service/playerrating', {ratingTotal:rating}, {params} );
      if (res.data.success) {

        //rest of code to continue here...
      }
      else {
        console.log(res.data.message); 
      }

      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.response.data.message);
      }
    }
    sendPlayerRating();
  };

 
 <div className="container">
                        <div className="weeklycount_graph_section">
                            <div>
                              <Button className="playerRatingBtn" variant="outlined" color="primary" onClick={() => handleClickOpen(setRandPlayerRating())}>
                                Enter Player Rating
                              </Button>
                              <Dialog
                                open={open}
                                onClose={handleClose}
                                aria-labelledby="skills-area"
                              >
                              <DialogTitle id="skills-area">Rate the skills of a player</DialogTitle>
                                <DialogContent>
                                    {
                                      randPlayers.map(({email, name, photo}) =>(
                                        <DialogContentText key="id">
                                          <Avatar alt="player" src={photo}/>                                          
                                          <Input  type="hidden" name="playertorate" value={email} onChange={onChange}></Input>
                                        </DialogContentText>
                                      ))
                                    }
                                  <TextField
                                    autoFocus
                                    onChange={onChange}
                                    margin="dense"
                                    name="shooting"
                                    label="Shooting"
                                    type="text"
                                    fullWidth
                                  />
                                  <TextField
                                    autoFocus
                                    onChange={onChange}
                                    margin="dense"
                                    name="dribbling"
                                    label="Dribbling"
                                    type="text"
                                    fullWidth
                                  />
                                  <TextField
                                    autoFocus
                                    onChange={onChange}
                                    margin="dense"
                                    name="ballcontrol"
                                    label="Ball Control"
                                    type="text"
                                    fullWidth
                                  />
                                  <TextField
                                    autoFocus
                                    onChange={onChange}
                                    margin="dense"
                                    name="sprinting"
                                    label="Sprinting"
                                    type="text"
                                    fullWidth
                                  />
                                   <TextField
                                    autoFocus
                                    onChange={onChange}
                                    margin="dense"
                                    name="fitness"
                                    label="Fitness"
                                    type="text"
                                    fullWidth
                                  />
                                </DialogContent>
                                <DialogActions>
                                  <Button onClick={handleClose} color="secondary">
                                    Cancel
                                  </Button>
                                  <Button onClick={() => handleClose(calculateAvgRating((ratingCalculation(rating))))} color="primary">
                                    Submit
                                  </Button>
                                </DialogActions>
                              </Dialog>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try and send ratePlyrEmail to the server side? you're only sending rating and params (which has loginUserEmail)
Maybe try changing params to this:
`const params = { email: loginUserEmail, ratingTotal: rating, ratePlyrEmail: ratePlyrEmail };
`

Comment: I have tried that, I could see individual  values of rating in the ratePlyrEmail field instead of email...

Comment: I will attach the screen shot for reference

Comment: I am not changing the input field, as it displays the email value randomly. Is that because of that ?

Comment: I mean the `onChange` is not picking up the email value ?

Comment: Kind of hard to understand anything... your onChange method is trying to be generic, but you end up updating both rating, and rateEmailValue.
And I can't understand from your code if you changed anything on the email input.

Comment: Should I be setting the email here in `onChange` like this .... `const rateEmailValue = {
      ...ratePlyrEmail,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    }
    setRatePlyrEmail(rateEmailValue);`

Comment: I am not changing anything on email input, the email will display randomly in that input field...<Input  type="hidden" name="playertorate" value={email} onChange={onChange}></Input>

Comment: In the above code, I am doing two things one is getting values of from different skills and calculating average and passing the avg value as rating in `calculateAvgRating ()`. Next I am trying to get email displays in the input with name `playertorate` field.

Comment: I still don't understand what you are trying to do.
the email input is not an input? It's being filled from a player? It's not suppose to change? then why do you put an onChange method on it?
Another question - what is randPlayers? where do you get that variable from?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217683/discussion-between-soccerway-and-nir-shabi).